# Rewrite to non-existing subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Let's say, I have a simple URL like /page/subpage/ and I want it (and it's subpages) to be fully accessible via /en/page/subpage/. What rewrite rules should I apply here? Already tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en/page/subpage/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page/subpage/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it redirects every URL, because of ^(.*)$ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it as below:

```
RewriteRule ^en/page/subpage/(.*)$ /page/subpage/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple rule:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(page/subpage/.*)$ $1 [L,NC]
```